# How to draw Harish Kumar's avatar in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following figure. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to the site](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). This is not a 'I would like you to do this for me' site so please show what you have so far.

Comment: How to finish depends on how you started! So, how did you start?

Comment: Is it my avatar or is there something wrong with my internet? :) :)

Comment: @HarishKumar: Nothing's wrong with your internets. :-)

Comment: Could it be that this is posted by a troll, and you(commenters) are being too nice?

Comment: Pay, say, 100$ to Harish Kumar, who is the owner of this avatar. A very nice finish of his work. :-)

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen If being too nice is wrong, than I don't want to be right :)

Comment: Where is Harish Kumar account btw?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can produce the image

[image]

using

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=transparent!0, outer color=transparent!100]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
       \draw[draw=magenta!60, line width=2pt, fill=yellow](0,0) rectangle (2,2);
       \fill [green,path fading=fade out] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
       \node[magenta] at (1,1) {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont HK};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Font courtesy of the real HK via the comments.

Comment: `\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont` ;)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a different avatar for you. Hope you will like it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
\pagecolor{fondpaille}
\color{Maroon}
\tkzSetUpColors[background=fondpaille,text=Maroon]
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
% from a figure d'O Reboux with pst-eucl ( D Rodriguez  )
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.8pt]
  \tkzInit[xmin=-6,ymin=-6,xmax=6,ymax=6]
  \tkzClip
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(132:4){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
  \foreach \ang in {5,10,...,360}{%
    \tkzDefPoint(\ang:5){M}
    \tkzDefLine[mediator](A,M)  \tkzGetPoints{i}{j}
    \tkzDrawLine[color=magenta,add= 4 and 4](i,j)}
  \node[scale=5,font=\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont] at (-2.5,2.1) {Qi};
  \node[scale=5,font=\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont] at (-1,0.75) {Wei};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So cool!!  Do you have others?

Comment: @xiaojidan It is just a matter of some ideas about the design and rest is TeXing :-) I don't have them ready but create them on the fly as and when needed.

Comment: Can you help me another question? [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207223/how-to-draw-some-lines-between-figures-in-latex)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-slpe}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(2,2)
\pscircle[dimen=i,fillstyle=ccslope,slopebegin=green,slopeend=yellow](1,1){!2 sqrt}
\rput(1,1){\color{magenta!60}\huge$\mathcal{HK}$}
\psframe[linecolor=magenta!60,linewidth=2pt](2,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a bug in your code!

Comment: @xiaojidan there is a bug in your comment: you say nothing about the error itself.

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 
                             
l.5 ...ebegin=green,slopeend=yellow](1,1){!2 sqrt}

Comment: @xiaojidan there is a bug in your compiler choice :) try using `xelatex`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Usually, I use pdflatex, so I seldomly use xelatex.