# How to draw some lines between figures in LaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots, graphics, tabularx

I want to draw the following figure. How do I do this? Some lines between figures, and Can you give me this lines some color?
[image]

Some color lines in figure, as following:
[image]

Comment: Use [`tabu`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tabu/tabu.pdf) package and put the figures a *table* `tabu`

Comment: Can you show codes in details?

Comment: It is not clear what you are aksing, but perhaps [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz/) is what you are looking for.  It would be lot easier to help you if your provided fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that shows what you have tried so far and sets up the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be some thing like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{arydshln,graphicx,xcolor,array}

\begin{document}
  \arrayrulecolor{magenta}%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{c;{2pt/2pt}c|}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{tabular}
  \arrayrulecolor{blue}%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{c;{2pt/2pt}c}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't mind using `tikz`, you may use `matrix` library of `tikz` and draw the lines in any way you like. This method is highly versatile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (a)[row sep=0mm, column sep=0mm, inner sep=1mm,  matrix of nodes] at (0,0) {
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} &
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b} &
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}\\
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} &
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b} &
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}\\\\
        };
%

\draw[thick,red] (a-1-1.north east) -- (a-2-1.south east);
\draw[thick,densely dashed,blue] (a-1-2.north east) -- (a-2-2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I insert some images in my paper. And it shows ok. Thank you versy much.